# will linux function inet_ntoa result in a dns query?

Tags: c, linux

Will linux function inet_ntoa result in a dns query in linux ?
Can anyone give some example on this ?
I want to limit the dns lookups made , in that case using inet_ntoa will result in a dns query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it just converts the given "binary coded" IPv4 address into a string.

BTW, together with IPv4, this function as well gets more and more "old-style". Besides that, it is not thread-safe as the buffer whose address is returned will be reused on every call.

If you use [`getnameinfo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo) in your programs and supply the flags `NI_NUMERICHOST` and `NI_NUMERICSERV`, the function will refrain from doing DNS queries as well, but it will display all types of addresses it knows about (mostly IPv4 and IPv6).

Answer (score 2):

No, [`inet_ntoa`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) just converts an address in 'raw binary' address (in network order) to its dotted-decimal representation.

[`getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) is used for DNS queries. The address it gets is in this raw binary form. `inet_ntoa` can then be used to make the address (more) human readable.

Note that even `getaddrinfo` may not necessarily result in a DNS query. Most OSes keep a DNS cache and serve the addres from there if it has been requested earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`inet_ntoa` is independent of DNS; it translates a 32-bit IPV4 address into the dotted-quad notation. `inet_addr` performs the reverse translation. Neither involve DNS names to address or address to name lookups.

Both are deprecated these days as "IPV4 only" in favor of the `inet_ntop` function that can handle IPV4 and IPV6 conversions.